# exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView". Symfony 4

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, symfony4

I've a problem about datas on my form view

The principle is the same as this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRfsHix1eRA&t=1257s), that is to say: when I select a "management" I want the "services" associated to this "management".
These must be selected in a "report Form" (Report Entity). 
OneOrMany service is linked to One management, and a report is linked to a management and a service.

Entities

Management.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ManagementRepository")
 */
class Management
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Service", mappedBy="management")
 */
private $services;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Report", mappedBy="management")
 */
private $reports;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->services = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->reports = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getName(): ?string
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName(string $name): self
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Service[]
 */
public function getServices(): Collection
{
    return $this->services;
}

public function addService(Service $service): self
{
    if (!$this->services->contains($service)) {
        $this->services[] = $service;
        $service->setManagement($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeService(Service $service): self
{
    if ($this->services->contains($service)) {
        $this->services->removeElement($service);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($service->getManagement() === $this) {
            $service->setManagement(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Report[]
 */
public function getReports(): Collection
{
    return $this->reports;
}

public function addReport(Report $report): self
{
    if (!$this->reports->contains($report)) {
        $this->reports[] = $report;
        $report->setManagement($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeReport(Report $report): self
{
    if ($this->reports->contains($report)) {
        $this->reports->removeElement($report);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($report->getManagement() === $this) {
            $report->setManagement(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
}
```

Service.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ReportRepository")
*/
class Report
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $assigned_date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=7, scale=2, nullable=true)
 */
private $time;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Game", inversedBy="reports")
 */
private $game;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Management", inversedBy="reports")
 */
private $management;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Service", inversedBy="reports")
 */
private $service;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Format", inversedBy="reports")
 */
private $format;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="reports")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $category;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="reports")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getAssignedDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->assigned_date;
}

public function setAssignedDate(\DateTimeInterface $assigned_date): self
{
    $this->assigned_date = $assigned_date;

    return $this;
}

public function getTime()
{
    return $this->time;
}

public function setTime($time): self
{
    $this->time = $time;

    return $this;
}

public function getGame(): ?Game
{
    return $this->game;
}

public function setGame(?Game $game): self
{
    $this->game = $game;

    return $this;
}

public function getManagement(): ?Management
{
    return $this->management;
}

public function setManagement(?Management $management): self
{
    $this->management = $management;

    return $this;
}

public function getService(): ?Service
{
    return $this->service;
}

public function setService(?Service $service): self
{
    $this->service = $service;

    return $this;
}

public function getFormat(): ?Format
{
    return $this->format;
}

public function setFormat(?Format $format): self
{
    $this->format = $format;

    return $this;
}

public function getCategory(): ?Category
{
    return $this->category;
}

public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
{
    $this->category = $category;

    return $this;
}

public function getUser(): ?User
{
    return $this->user;
}

public function setUser(?User $user): self
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}
}
```

Report.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ReportRepository")
 */
class Report
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $assigned_date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=7, scale=2, nullable=true)
 */
private $time;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Game", inversedBy="reports")
 */
private $game;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Management", inversedBy="reports")
 */
private $management;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Service", inversedBy="reports")
 */
private $service;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Format", inversedBy="reports")
 */
private $format;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="reports")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $category;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="reports")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getAssignedDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->assigned_date;
}

public function setAssignedDate(\DateTimeInterface $assigned_date): self
{
    $this->assigned_date = $assigned_date;

    return $this;
}

public function getTime()
{
    return $this->time;
}

public function setTime($time): self
{
    $this->time = $time;

    return $this;
}

public function getGame(): ?Game
{
    return $this->game;
}

public function setGame(?Game $game): self
{
    $this->game = $game;

    return $this;
}

public function getManagement(): ?Management
{
    return $this->management;
}

public function setManagement(?Management $management): self
{
    $this->management = $management;

    return $this;
}

public function getService(): ?Service
{
    return $this->service;
}

public function setService(?Service $service): self
{
    $this->service = $service;

    return $this;
}

public function getFormat(): ?Format
{
    return $this->format;
}

public function setFormat(?Format $format): self
{
    $this->format = $format;

    return $this;
}

public function getCategory(): ?Category
{
    return $this->category;
}

public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
{
    $this->category = $category;

    return $this;
}

public function getUser(): ?User
{
    return $this->user;
}

public function setUser(?User $user): self
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}
}
```

FormType

ReportType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Report;
use App\Entity\Game;
use App\Entity\Management;
use App\Entity\Service;
use App\Entity\Format;
use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;


class ReportType extends AbstractType
{
protected $tokenStorage;

public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    $builder->add('assigned_date', DateType::class, array(
        'widget' => 'single_text',

        // prevents rendering it as type="date", to avoid HTML5 date pickers
        'html5' => false,

        // adds a class that can be selected in JavaScript
        'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
    ));
    $builder->add('time');
    $builder->add('game', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => Game::class,
        'placeholder' => '',
        'choice_label' => 'name'));
    $builder->add('management', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => Management::class,
        'placeholder' => 'Select a management',
        'mapped' => false,
        'choice_label' => 'name'));
    $builder->get('management')->addEventListener(
      FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
      function (FormEvent $event)
      {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $form->getParent()->add('service',EntityType::class, array(
          'class' => Service::class,
          'placeholder' => 'Select a service',
          'choices'     => $form->getData()->getServices()
        ));
      }
    );
    $builder->add('format', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => Format::class,
        'placeholder' => '',
        'choice_label' => 'name'));
    $builder->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => Category::class,
        'placeholder' => '',
        'choice_label' => 'name'));
    $builder->add('user', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => User::class,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
          $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->Where('u.id='. $user->getId());
        },
        'choice_label' => 'id',
      ));
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Report::class,
    ]);
}
}
```

Twig associated

_form.twig.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Report;
use App\Form\ReportType;
use App\Repository\ReportRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/report")
 */
class ReportController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 * @Route("/", name="report_index", methods="GET")
 */
public function index(ReportRepository $reportRepository): Response
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
    $user = $this->getUser()->getId();
    return $this->render('report/index.html.twig', ['reports' => $reportRepository->findAllByIdUser($user)]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/new", name="report_new", methods="GET|POST")
 */
public function new(Request $request): Response
{
    $report = new Report();
    $form = $this->createForm(ReportType::class, $report);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($report);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('report_index');
    }

    return $this->render('report/new.html.twig', [
        'report' => $report,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/{id}", name="report_show", methods="GET")
 */
public function show(Report $report): Response
{
    return $this->render('report/show.html.twig', ['report' => $report]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="report_edit", methods="GET|POST")
 */
public function edit(Request $request, Report $report): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(ReportType::class, $report);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('report_edit', ['id' => $report->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('report/edit.html.twig', [
        'report' => $report,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/{id}", name="report_delete", methods="DELETE")
 */
public function delete(Request $request, Report $report): Response
{
    if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$report->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($report);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('report_index');
}
}
```

When I dump() my $form->getData()->getServices(), this return a collection. but i've this message : Neither the property "service" nor one of the methods "service()", "getservice()"/"isservice()"/"hasservice()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".

on {{ form_widget(form.service, { 'attr': {'placeholder': "Service"} }) }}

Some people have a solution ?

I can provide more information if you need it
Thank you.

Comment: Could it be that you get this error because twig tries to render the `service` field of your form, which is only added on `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT` and therefore not there yet? You can use Symfony's profiler to check what your form's data looks like, maybe you should temporarily remove that line of twig that causes the issue and check in the profiler that all the fields are the way you want them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. in profiler, service collection is empty... it doesn't get datas. Have you got any solutions to get datas dynamically when i choose an option in select ? it's posible to get datas with the repository and passed in parameters the Management 'id' ?

does it better for use AngularJS for this ?